# Fix workspace bounds

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to set the workspace bound for my robot. I know there is a functionality in moveit that helps you to do that. It is called "fix workspace bounds". Anybody has some example code in python I could use to understand how it works ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270389/fix-workspace-bounds/) by [raf4343](https://answers.ros.org/users/29192/raf4343/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The (whole) code for the module `fix_workspace_bounds` can be found [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_ros/planning/planning_request_adapter_plugins/src/fix_workspace_bounds.cpp).

As you can see there, you can set a ROS parameter `(move_group/)default_workspace_bounds` that specifies the distance of the boundary from origin in all three dimensions.
I didn't look thoroughly, but I guess you have to pass in the workspace explicitly if you want non-cubic workspace bounds.

Be aware though that the workspace concept **does not affect revolution joints**.
It is meant for floating and planar joints.

If you want your fixed robot arm to stay within a volume, add wall collision objects in the area that should be avoided.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3